# Invoke Method never returns

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates

I have a thread running, which grabs images from a camera, saves them, and updates the pictureBox to display that bitmap. When I want to exit the application, I set my bool `exitApplication` to true, but it never returns on the `join()` call.

```
    public void GrabThread()
    {
        Bitmap copyBmp;
        while (!exitApplication)
        {
            mImage = m_camera.GrabImage();
            SaveImage();

            copyBmp = (Bitmap)mImage.bmp.Clone();
            if (pictureBox1.InvokeRequired)
            {
                pictureBox1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(
                delegate ()
                {
                    pictureBox1.Image = copyBmp;
                }));
            }
            else
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = copyBmp;
            }
            m_camera.ReleaseImage();
        }
    }
```

My Exit code:

```
        exitApplication = true;
        threadGrab.Join();
        m_camera.Stop();
        Close();
```

When I call Break All from the Debug menu, the Thread hangs at

```
pictureBox1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(
delegate ()
{
    pictureBox1.Image = copyBmp;
}));
```

Why? And how can I prevent this? Currently I have to call Abort() on the thread to exit it.

Comment: `Invoke` will execute its call on the UI thread. If that thread is busy, it will block. The easy solution is to separate the background from the UI code and use `await` to await for the background code to finish without blocking, before getting back to the UI thread.

Comment: Okay, I understand that since I am in the Button Clicked method, the UI Thread is waiting. As it is waiting, the invoke is never called, resulting in a deadlock. What does the Await() do, or rather, how to use it? I changed my code right now to instead use Environment.Exit(0) when the grab thread stops.

Comment: On the contrary, `Invoke` *is* called but the UI thread is already blocked by `threadGrab.Join();`. This causes a deadlock - the background thread is waiting for the UI thread to unblock, but *that* thread is in turn waiting for the background thread to finish.

Comment: As for how to fix the code, what's the part that needs to run in the background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code deadlocks because `pictureBox1.Invoke` is trying to execute code in the UI thread. That thread though is blocked by the call to `threadGrab.Join();`

This can be fixed using `async/await`. `await` awaits already executing asynchronous tasks without blocking the way `Join()` does. When it finishes, execution resumes in the original synchronization context. In a WinForms or WPF application, this means execution resumes on the UI thread.

I assume the only thing that needs to run in the background is `m_camera.GrabImage();`. In that case, the code could look something like this :

```
public async void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    await Task.Run(()=>m_camera.GrabImage();
    //Back in the UI thread
    SaveImage();
    var copyBmp = (Bitmap)mImage.bmp.Clone();
    pictureBox1.Image = copyBmp;
    m_camera.ReleaseImage();
}
```

`Task.Run` will execute `m_camera.GrabImage()` in a threadpool thread. `await` will await for this to finish without blocking the UI thread. When it finishes, execution resumes in the UI thread which means there's no need for `Invoke`.

This could run in a loop too :

```
public async void Capture_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    while(someCondition)
    {
        await Task.Run(()=>m_camera.GrabImage();

        SaveImage();
        var copyBmp = (Bitmap)mImage.bmp.Clone();
        pictureBox1.Image = copyBmp;
        m_camera.ReleaseImage();
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed it instead to `await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => threadGrab.Join());` which worked, and the application would exit. Not entirely sure about this whole thing, but I get no errors it appears.

Comment: The point is that you *don't* need the extra thread or `Join()`. `Task.Run` already uses a different thread, there's no reason to use *another* one. `await` does what `Join()` would do and more, without blocking the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

It may not the right answer but you can using both OnClosing and OnClosed to Stop your camera then close your app, I don't know does it work in Winform but it worked with me in WPF

```
protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
{

            e.Cancel = false; //prevent your application to shutdown
            Camera.Stop(); //stop your camera
            base.OnClosing(e);

}

protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
{
            base.OnClosed(e);
            Application.Current.Shutdown(); //then shutdown again
}
```

Via 2 step, your camera will stop without Join any thread. And note that this code is written in Wpf, not Winform but I thought you can find a similar way to do in Winform

Hope this answer may help you.